# Emmet custom html snippet for meta media query

Tags: html, emmet

I want to make a custom html code abbreviation for emmet in SublimeText 2. For example, I can use link:css which expands to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Now I'd like to use link:media to expand to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:000px) and 
(max-width:000px)" href="style.css">
```

I've thought I found a part of the solution by going to:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Emmet
```

and in this file: Emmet.sublime-settings, I've added this code, under the section titled "snippets": { ...

```
// can be improved
    "html": {
        "abbreviations": {
            "link:mqm": "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"only screen and (min-width:",
            "mqx": "and (max-width:"
        }
    }
```

... but it's not working. Plus, I really want to do this: I want to combine both "link:mqm" and "mqx" into a single abbreviation - link:media - that will, when hitting TAB once, lead to after "min-width", so that I can put in the first pixel value, and upon hitting TAB the second time, it will go to after the "max-width" so I can put in the second pixel value.

Anyone done anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution.

First, there is a snippets.json file at this location:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Emmet\emmet
```

It lists all abbreviations, so I've looked under "html", and then I've found "link:css". This one I used as a template for my own snippet.

Next, I've opened the file Emmet.sublime-settings, at this location:

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Emmet
```

and I've found that the "settings" section actually adds to (or should I say "overrides") the aforementioned "settings.json" file. Now in this "settings" section, I've added this code:

```
        "html": {
        "abbreviations": {
            "link:media": "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"only screen and (min-width:${1:50}px) and (max-width:${2:500}px)\" href=\"${3:style}.css\" />"
        }
    },
```

... and it works just as I wanted.